# How would i run a Rust program without a window only when it's in release mode

Tags: rust

I have a Rust project I'm currently working on and I frequently have to debug and deploy it. While it's deployed it runs in the background without a window but when I'm debugging I want a window to see if there are any runtime errors.

I currently use `#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]` and comment it out whenever I'm debugging, but is there a way for the program itself to check if it's in debug mode so it doesn't use that flag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `#![cfg_attr(predicate, attribute)]` to only compile with an attribute if the specific predicate evaluates to true.

As for what the predicate is, my recommendation would be use an explicit [feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg_attr-attribute) (e.g. `console`) that you set when you want to build with the non-default behavior (e.g. having the console window appear).

Additionally, if you want to have your code be portable, you should also check that you are compiling for Windows.

In `Cargo.toml`:

```
[features]
console = []
```

In `main.rs`:

```rust
#![cfg_attr(
  all(
    target_os = "windows",
    not(feature = "console"),
  ),
  windows_subsystem = "windows"
)]
```

Then you can compile or run with `--features console`  to have the default `console` subsystem be used instead.

---

If you want to actually check for the debug mode, the closest you can get is the [`debug_assertions`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#debug_assertions) predicate, which is enabled by default when compiling without optimizations.

In `main.rs`:

```rust
#![cfg_attr(
  all(
    target_os = "windows",
    not(debug_assertions),
  ),
  windows_subsystem = "windows"
)]
```

Comment: Is there a way to check this at runtime? I would like to give my program a --debug flag so i can run the release version with console output if required.